# Twitter Authentication "Could not authenticate you." error

Tags: php, api, oauth, twitter

Hey, I'm in the process of creating a new website which signs you in with your Twitter account. But when I'm testing the authentication I'm getting the above error. Here's the whole thing I'm getting:

```
stdClass Object ( 
[request] => /1/account/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=*********&oauth_nonce=*********************&oauth_signature=****************************&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1302636413&oauth_token=&oauth_version=1.0 
[error] => Could not authenticate you. 
)
```

Please help if you know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Zend_Service_Twitter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html)?  A colleague has used it for some PHP-centric Twitter contracts, and hasn't had any complaints.

The call in your question would translate to this:

```
$twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
    'username' => 'johndoe',
    'accessToken' => $token
));
$response = $twitter->account->verifyCredentials();
```

If you haven't already obtained the access token from Twitter, then use [Zend_OAuth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html).